# anythingSlider - Caption no longer animating

Tags: jquery, anythingslider

I've began skinning, configuring and implementing the anythingSlider into a jsFiddle project and I noticed that once I implemented the thumbnail/slider system, my captions are no longer animating on transition/load. The jQuery may be conflicting with each other in the javaScript box.

You can check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/fKCFE/.

In theory, the caption should slide in from under the image and display itself onLoad of the slide/transition from one slide to another.

Here is an example of it working the way I would prefer: http://jsfiddle.net/jodriscoll/fKCFE/51/

```
// caption toggle animation time
var toggleTime = 500,
// always show caption when slide comes into view
showCaptionInitially = true,

updateCaption = function(slider, init) {
    if (init && showCaptionInitially) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            slider.$targetPage.find('.caption').animate({
                bottom: 0
            }, toggleTime);
        }, slider.options.delayBeforeAnimate + toggleTime);
    } else if (!init) {
        var cap = slider.$lastPage.find('.caption');
        cap.css('bottom', -cap.innerHeight());
    }
};

$('#slider').anythingSlider({
//  buildNavigation : false,
// *********** Callbacks ***********
// Callback when the plugin finished initializing
onInitialized: function(e, slider) {
    slider.$items.each(function() {
        var cap = $(this).find('.caption');
        cap.css('bottom', -cap.innerHeight()).click(function() {
            cap.animate({
                bottom: (cap.css('bottom') === "0px" ? -cap.innerHeight() : 0)
            }, toggleTime);
        });
    });
    updateCaption(slider, true);
},

// Callback before slide animates
onSlideBegin: function(e, slider) {
    updateCaption(slider, true);
},

// Callback after slide animates
onSlideComplete: function(slider) {
    updateCaption(slider, false);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that that slider was being initialized twice. Any code in the second instance is ignored. Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/fKCFE/56/) with code combined from both.

```
// ******************
// Thumnail Slider
// ******************
var fadeTime = 0,
    fadeDelay = 0,
    timer,
    hideControls = function (slider) {
        clearTimeout(timer);
        setTimeout(function () {
            slider.$controls.fadeOut(fadeTime);
            $('.tooltip').fadeOut(fadeTime);
        }, fadeDelay);
    },
    // ******************
    // Caption animation
    // ******************
    toggleTime = 500,
    showCaptionInitially = true,
    updateCaption = function (slider, init) {
        if (init && showCaptionInitially) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                slider.$targetPage.find('.caption').animate({
                    bottom: 0
                }, toggleTime);
            }, slider.options.delayBeforeAnimate + toggleTime);
        } else if (!init) {
            var cap = slider.$lastPage.find('.caption');
            cap.css('bottom', -cap.innerHeight());
        }
    };

$('#slider').anythingSlider({
    navigationSize: 3,
    navigationFormatter: function (i, panel) {
        var url = 'http://www.massgeneral.org/international/dev/assets/slideshow/slideshow-',
            thumbs = [
                ['01', 'This is the tooltip for the first thumbnail'],
                ['02', 'This is the tooltip for the second thumbnail'],
                ['03', 'This is the tooltip for the third thumbnail'],
                ['04', 'This is the tooltip for the fourth thumbnail'],
                ['05', 'This is the tooltip for the fifth thumbnail'], ];
        return '<img title="' + thumbs[i - 1][1] + '" src="' + url + thumbs[i - 1][0] + '.jpg">';
    },
    onInitialized: function (e, slider) {
        slider.$items.each(function () {
            var cap = $(this).find('.caption');
            cap.css('bottom', -cap.innerHeight()).click(function () {
                cap.animate({
                    bottom: (cap.css('bottom') === "0px" ? -cap.innerHeight() : 0)
                }, toggleTime);
            });
        });
        updateCaption(slider, true);
        slider.$controls.find('img').tooltip();
    },
    onSlideBegin: function (e, slider) {
        updateCaption(slider, true);
    },
    onSlideComplete: function (slider) {
        updateCaption(slider, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Mottie, thanks for responding! I greatly appreciate your hard work on the AnythingSlider!

Comment: Would it be possible to check out a couple more questions I had about your slider on your github -or- do you want me to post the questions on stackoverflow instead?

Comment: Well, I'd like to think that github issues are for bug and enhancement requests. So here is fine, or even better in the [css-tricks forums](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussions).